# pacman a file owned by two packages

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

i have installed microchip and jlink softwares from aur on my system.
unfortunately this two packages own 99-jlink.rules file so i had to force install jlink. but now pacman and yaourt give me this error:

```
error: file owned by 'jlink-software-and-documentation' and 'microchip-mplabx-bin': 'etc/udev/rules.d/99-jlink.rules'
```

both pacman and yaourt are working perfectly but giving this error at the end of every transaction...
any ideas how to fix this?(I need both softwares,so removal of one is not an option!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your issue is related tp packages 1st installed by pacman and later on you try to install same packages with yaourt

1st uninstall with pacman the pakages pacman -R and install with yaourt -S